# Show more / less jquery issue when adding paragraphs or ul/li tag content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to implement a show  more /less effect in my website, and I picked a code on the internet (as many do), and it works great. But when I add text with paragraphs or ul/li tag content, it doesn't work anymore, I don't know why.

Here is my code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Configure/customize these variables.
    var showChar = 100; // How many characters are shown by default
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "Show more >";
    var lesstext = "Show less";
    

    $('.more').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();
 
        if(content.length > showChar) {
 
            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
 
            var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
 
            $(this).html(html);
        }
 
    });
 
    $(".morelink").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
.morecontent span {
    display: none;
}
.morelink {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
    <div class="more">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p><ul><li>consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</li><li> ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</li><li> quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</li></ul> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
```

Please help !

Comment: works fine - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/oLaQvE  are you getting any errors in console

Comment: Make sure you include jQuery on top of your page: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Normally, when the page loads for the first time, only 100 characters of the text must be displayed, but in my case, it doesn't, because the whole content of text is displayed (instead of 100 characters). Furthermore, when I click on "show more", the text shortens itself instead of expand.

Comment: @JadeKallo thx, I already did, but my issue remains.